# Route Change command with Powershell Captureing output

Tags: powershell

I am trying to capture the output of the route change command.

```
$StrTemp = route change 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 $Gateway metric 10 if $i
```

If the interface does not exist the output is not captured into $StrTemp. If the command is successful it is captured. Placing the | Out-Null command doesn't change anything either. Any error in the command is still printed on the screen. Anyone found this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It likely outputs to `stderr` on failure, you can merge it with `stdout` using the `>` redirection operator:

```
$routeOut = route change 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 $Gateway metric 10 if $i 2>&1
$routeErr = $routeOut.Where({$_ -eq [System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord]})
```

or wrap it in an expression and then capture it using the `ErrorVariable` parameter:

```
$routeOut = Invoke-Expression "route change 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 $Gateway metric 10 if $i" -ErrorVariable routeErr
```

Comment: Thanks.  First one was it. Invoke-Expression didnt capture it